# Guardar imágenes desde ventana modal con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

estoy tratando de grabar una imagen a la base de datos desde una ventana modal pero no entiendo cual es mi problema.
mi controlador

```
 public function agregarFoto(Request $request, $id) {
    // var_dump($request->id); die;
    $producto = Product::findOrFail($request->id);
    if(Input::hasFile('$request->image')) {
        $file=Input::file('$request->image');
        Image::make($request->file('image'))
            ->resize(244, 245)
            ->save(public_path().'/imagenes/productos/' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $producto->image=$file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    if($producto->save()){
        return redirect("/product_list")->with('success', 'Imagen agregada correctamente!');
    }else{
        return redirect("/product_list")->with('warnning', 'No se puedo agregar el archivo!');
    }

}
```

mi vista

```
<table id="example" class="display table" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Acciones</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($products as $product)
              <tr>
                  <td>
                    <!-- <a href="{{url('/agregarFoto', $product->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-camera"></a> -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal{{$product->id}}">
                      Launch demo modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
                  <td>{{$product->description}}</td>
                  <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
                  <td>foto.jpg</td>
              </tr>


              <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal{{$product->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <form action="{{url('/agregarFoto', $product->id)}}" accept="image/jpeg" method="POST">
                  {{Form::token()}}
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
                    <input type="file" name="image">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

y mi ruta

```
Route::post('/agregarFoto/{id}', 'ProductController@agregarFoto');
```

El problema es que en mi controlador no me reconoce la imagen,al hacer un var_dump(Input::hasFile('$request->image')) me tira false.. alguna ayuda?

Comment: ahora hice un dd(Input::hasFile()); y salta un error:  Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Http\Request::hasFile(), 0 passed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo me faltaba agregar esto a mi formulario `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Que bueno que hayas encontrado la solución. Recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) después de pasadas 48 horas. Saludos.